# Failed to load agent library: Agent_OnAttach is not available in management_agent

Tags: java, java-11, lib, .so

**QUESTION-1**

I'm trying to load the management_agent (libmanagement_agent.so library) into the jvm to set gc compilation vm argument on runtime.
This is my code snippet

```
long pid = getProcessId();
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(Long.toString(pid));
vm = VirtualMachine.attach(Long.toString(pid));
Properties agentProperties = vm.getAgentProperties();

String options = agentProperties.getProperty("sun.jvm.args");               
String connectorAddress = vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress");
options += " -Xlog:gc*:file=gc.log";
agentProperties.setProperty("sun.jvm.args", options);
            
vm.loadAgentLibrary("management_agent",options);
vm.detach();
```

I'm trying to load the manage_agent library along with the updated set of vm arguments

But the agent is not loaded, I'm getting the following error

> com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Failed to load agent library: Agent_OnAttach is not available in management_agent
> at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.execute(VirtualMachineImpl.java:220)
> at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:94)
> at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:119)
> at JdkLogs.main(gclogs.java:48)

Based on java official documentation, Agent_OnAttach is present in libmanagement_agent.so. My java version is 11.

**QUESTION-2**

I can load the agent by uing local manage agent
`vm.startLocalManagementAgent();`

Is there any possibility to add the vm argument to the agent loaded by this way

---

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: “_Based on java official documentation, Agent_OnAttach is present in libmanagement_agent.so._” Do you have a link? Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11%2B28/src/jdk.management.agent/unix/native/libmanagement_agent/FileSystemImpl.c) `Agent_OnAttach` is not present.